# How do get photos from your photo stream on your PC

Tags: icloud, windows, photos, photo-stream

Ok so I downloaded the iCloud program for Windows and synced my photo stream with my PC but only 100 pictures went onto my PC. There are still another 500 pictures in my photo stream on my iPhone. How can I get them to download to my PC as well?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that turning on Photostream on any particular device will only start to pull new photos added from that point in time onwards, and not grab the historically stored photos.

Comment: Ok it was on since I got the phone,all my photos are on photostream and are even taking up space on my iphone :>

Comment: But the Windows Device was perhaps set up to sync photos some time later?  When a photo is taken on a device that is using Photostream, it uploads it to iCloud, which then drops a note to other subscribed photostreams to tell them there is a new pic.  These messages don't get relayed historically to the new devices once you setup iCloud on them, only new ones.

Comment: Ah ok,that sucks.You would think apple would implement and update mechanism seeing as they charge so much for their products! :P

Comment: iCloud is free, the storage for your photostream is free.  The key is in the word "stream", it's not a sync tool.  You listen to the stream, and you can only get what is streamed since you started to listen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've had the same problem. Plugged my phone in as this is the way I've always done it, kind of like a hard drive. I panicked when there were only 15 images.... turns out I just needed to update my internet explorer... and download an up dated icloud I can now see all my photos woop woop.  Hope this helps x